# oracle Unable to create AWR report

Tags: oracle, snapshot, awr

oracle version: 11.2.0.1.0

When I try to generate an AWR Report in Oracle use sysdba,

```
exec dbms_workload_repository.create_snapshot();
```

I keep getting this error:

```
ORA-00600:  [kewrose_1], [600], [ORA-00600: [13013], [5001], [6213], [8465936], [5], [8447794], [17], [], [], [], [], []
], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
```

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this

Comment: this is happen to some of previous servers, do you try to bounce database to release resource and run awr again, these problem were fixed 12c.

Comment: it is running on pruduction env, do not restart

Answer (score 0):

conn / as sysdba

SQL> @$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/awrrpt.sql

SQL> @$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/awrrpt.sql

Current Instance

```
   DB Id    DB Name      Inst Num Instance
----------- ------------ -------- ------------
 3400239050 TEP                 1 TEP


Specify the Report Type
```

AWR reports can be generated in the following formats.  Please enter the
name of the format at the prompt.  Default value is 'html'.

'html'          HTML format (default)
'text'          Text format
'active-html'   Includes Performance Hub active report

Enter value for report_type: dec

Type Specified:  dec

Instances in this Workload Repository schema

```
   DB Id     Inst Num DB Name      Instance     Host
------------ -------- ------------ ------------ ------------
* 3400239050        1 TEPCBC          TEP          oldman

Using 3400239050 for database Id
Using          1 for instance number


Specify the number of days of snapshots to choose from
```

Entering the number of days (n) will result in the most recent
(n) days of snapshots being listed.  Pressing  without
specifying a number lists all completed snapshots.
Entering the number of days (n) will result in the most recent
(n) days of snapshots being listed.  Pressing  without
specifying a number lists all completed snapshots.

Enter value for num_days: 1

Listing the last day's Completed Snapshots

```
                                                    Snap
```

Instance     DB Name        Snap Id    Snap Started    Level

---

TEP          TEP              38542 20 Dec 2022 00:30      1

```
                          38543 20 Dec 2022 01:30      1

                          38544 20 Dec 2022 02:30      1
                          38545 20 Dec 2022 03:30      1

                          38546 20 Dec 2022 04:30      1
                          38547 20 Dec 2022 05:30      1

                          38548 20 Dec 2022 06:30      1
                          38549 20 Dec 2022 07:30      1

                          38550 20 Dec 2022 08:30      1
                          38551 20 Dec 2022 09:30      1
                          38552 20 Dec 2022 10:30      1

                          38553 20 Dec 2022 11:30      1
                          38554 20 Dec 2022 12:30      1
                          38555 20 Dec 2022 13:30      1
                          38556 20 Dec 2022 14:30      1

                          38557 20 Dec 2022 15:30      1
                          38558 20 Dec 2022 16:30      1
                          38559 20 Dec 2022 17:30      1
                          38560 20 Dec 2022 18:30      1
                          38561 20 Dec 2022 19:30      1
                          38562 20 Dec 2022 20:30      1
```

Specify the Begin and End Snapshot Ids

```
Enter value for begin_snap: 38542
Begin Snapshot Id specified: 38542

Enter value for end_snap: 38544
End   Snapshot Id specified: 38544



Specify the Report Name
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
The default report file name is awrrpt_1_38542_38544.html.  To use this name,
press <return> to continue, otherwise enter an alternative.

Enter value for report_name: test2

Using the report name test2

<html lang="en"><head><title>AWR Report for DB: TEP, Inst: TEP, Snaps: 38542-38544</title>
<style type="text/css">
body.awr {font:bold 10pt Arial,Helvetica,Geneva,sans-serif;color:black; background:White;}
```